# <video> tag doesn't set volume of remote MediaStream from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I recieve  remote MediaStream and set it to video:

```
this.Video = document.createElement("video");
this.Video.autoplay = 1;
this.Video.style.visibility = "hidden";
this.Video.style.float = "left";
this.Video.width = CAMERA_VIDEO_SIZES.SMALL;
this.Video.height = CAMERA_VIDEO_SIZES.SMALL;
this.Video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
this.Video.volume = 0;
```

But if I set REMOTE MediaStream, volume isn't controlled (volume = 0, but I still hear sound)!
And if I set LOCAL MediaStream, volume is controlled!
How can that be?? And what I must to do to control Remote MediaStream  volume?

Comment: Won't help you on your problem (which sounds like a bug in your browser's implementation), but don't use `createObjectURL(MediaStream)`. This is deprecated. Instead, use `vid.srcObject = MediaStream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, guys! There was bug in my code... I made frankenstein from another program, with some parts from this program, and it works fine!!!